# how to make a optional variable?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
@bee.command(name="돈얼마", description="지갑 지갑을 보자!")
async def 돈얼마(interaction: discord.Interaction, 멘션: discord.User):
    userid = 멘션.id
    embed=discord.Embed(title="돈 지급", description=f"잔액 : {money[userid]}원\n" + f"이정도 밖에 없는건 아니죠? 에이", color=0x5cff67)
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

this code and I want to make this part an optional parameter > "멘션: discord.User"

I don't know Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_function_default_parameter.asp

You can also use `None` as default parameter and handle it in other way:

```
@bee.command(name="돈얼마", description="지갑 지갑을 보자!")
async def 돈얼마(interaction: discord.Interaction, 멘션: discord.User = None):
    if 멘션 is not None:
        userid = 멘션.id
        embed=discord.Embed(title="돈 지급", description=f"잔액 : {money[userid]}원\n" + f"이정도 밖에 없는건 아니죠? 에이", color=0x5cff67)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
    else:
        foo() # replace with code to execute when 멘션 is not given
```

When 멘션 is given, it will execute as usually, otherwise `foo()` will be executed.